# How to set up an index domain for an AIMMS constraint

Tags: aimms

We have a set of constraints which should be satisfied "for all k,l element of U, and k=/=l". How do we specify this in the 'index domain' line for specifying constraints?

Answer (score 0):

Define your set `U` to have multiple indices: `k, l` (simply fill in multiple indices in the index field of your set `U`).
Then, for the index domain in your constraint, use `(k, l) | k <> l`. This is the set of pairs `(k, l)`, which you have defined to be in `U`, restricted to the set `k` not equal to `l`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Abby reply, you can use any expression that returns a true or false in the condition for your (k, l) indexes. So you can place a parameter instead of the inequality.